# Is it possible to enable/disable 'Application does not run in background'?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to enable/disable 'Application does not run in background'?
I know I can set the value in .plist. But I prefer to set it via codes.

Comment: Its not possible. Do you want to make the decision to run in background or not based on some conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly opt-out via the property list setting you prefer not to use. There's no API to do this that is public.